# How to clear the key in the specified list in Redis?

Tags: redis

Redis has the following data:

```
key         value
code1       num1
code2       num2
...
code6000000 num6000000
```

I have a **known** **fixed** list which is not regular：

```
{code1, code3, code11, ..., code1234567}
```

How should I **design Redis** so that I can easily **delete** these kv?

Answer (score 3):

Redis has a data structure like hash table [this](https://redis.io/commands/hset/).

you can easily follow instructions there to accomplish your needs.

Example:

```
redis:6379> HSET myhash field1 "Hello"
(integer) 1

redis:6379> HGET myhash field1
"Hello"

redis:6379> HDEL myhash field1
(integer) 1
```

Comment: Using this approach means that I have to change the current redis storage structure, which requires the caller to adapt to the new protocol, which is not possible. Do you think there is another way?

Comment: @dearwangsen
If you already have the set (or list) of keys, know that you can use `redis-cli> DEL key1 key2`. It means `DEL` command can accept multiple input. But I suggest you to redesign because separated key,value is not good when redis want to persist data.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to delete some keys that are stored in a Redis list, you can use this one line shell script in Linux:

```
> redis-cli  LRANGE mylist 0 -1 | xargs redis-cli  DEL
```